# Hadoop java mapper -copyFromLocal heap size error

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, jvm, heap-memory

As part of my Java mapper I have a command executes some code on the local node and copies a local output file to the hadoop fs.  Unfortunately I'm getting the following output:

> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>
> Could not reserve enough space for object heap

I've tried adjusting mapred.map.child.java.opts to -Xmx512M, but unfortunately no luck.

When I ssh into the node, I can run the -copyFromLocal command without any issues.  The ouput files are also quite small like around 100kb.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: check the log files and post any exception if any.

Comment: unfortunately no exception in log files ...

Comment: How does the "command executes some code on the local noce" looks like? Do you fork another process?

Comment: Yeah just another process executed through processbuilder, sorry not really up to speed with all the coding lingo

Comment: I've written about ProcessBuilder and Hadoop, it is about OOM errors, maybe it helps you: http://codingwiththomas.blogspot.com/2011/07/dealing-with-outofmemoryerror-in-hadoop.html

Comment: thanks for sharing your post, unfortunately haven't been able to fix it

Comment: @Joris: Have you ever managed to fix this issue? I encounter the same issue with a pretty small file..

Answer (score 0):

An infinite loop in the mapper or reducer can cause Out of memory errors.

I ran into an OoM once when I had a while-loop with iterator.hasNext() as the condition, for the reducer values, and was not calling iterator.next() inside the loop.